# subversion command in antscript pass argument as variable

Tags: svn, ant

how can i pass variable in the command instead of hard coding it.  I am running this subversion command in ant script to checkout latest code and I want to pass the destination folder and username and password as variables.  Is it possible?

```
<exec executable="svn"> 
    <arg line="co -r HEAD http://10.208.72.62/svn/test/trunk      
c:\CruiseControl\projects\svnTest\svn --username admin --password admin" />     
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a property for each parameter, either inline your antscript:

```
<!-- also possible to use property name=... location=... -->
<property name="destdir" value="c:/CruiseControl/projects/svnTest/svn"/>
<property name="username" value="admin"/>
<property name="pass" value="admin"/>
```

or create some propertyfile foo.properties with the lines :

```
:: use path separator unix style '/', java(ant) will handle it correctly
:: no need to use '\\'
destdir=c:/CruiseControl/projects/svnTest/svn
username=admin
pass=admin
```

and load it into your antscript via :

```
<property file="foo.properties"/>
```

then your exec task will look like :

```
<exec executable="svn"> 
 <arg line="co -r HEAD http://10.208.72.62/svn/test/trunk      
${destdir} --username ${username} --password ${pass}" />     
</exec>
```

see ant manual > [property task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) for details.